# DataGrid1_Selectionchanged not performed after first click on gridrow

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, datagrid

i have only one row in my grid, when i click on a gridrow one particular cell value is stored into textbox. I have a button, when click on button that textbox value is cleared. After i clear the textbox i click again on the same gridrow but its not sending any value to textbox.

```
`private void DataGrid1_Selectionchanged(object sender,SelectionChangedEventArgse)
    {
       var selectedRow = DataGrid1.SelectedItem;
       TextBox1.Text = selectedRow.coloumnName.ToString();                
    }

    private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = "";``
    }`
```

Comment: Would you place a breakpoint inside the selection changed handler and step through the code. It will tell you what is going on

Comment: @efekctive for first click its working good. when i click on the button and click again in the gridrow it's not coming to that handler

Answer (score 0):

Edit your button's `CommandName` property and set it to 'Select'
Or enable auto generate select button of the GridView.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogenerateselectbutton(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The selection changed handler is not firing because you have one row. The first time works but the second time there is nothing to change to. Change the handler or add a second row